# How do you delete null objects (not values) from a list

Tags: java

I have objects of a class Choice which are in a list.

Choice looks like this.

```
public class Choice extends MorphiaModel{   
    public String name;
    public Double price;
}
```

Some of them are empty, that is name is "" and price is null.

I want to remove these empty values.

I tried iterating over the list and removing them empty Choice objects, but I got a ConcurrentModificationException then I did this (after implementing equals and hashcode), but it doesn't work, the empty values are still there.

Note: option.choices is a list of Choice objects

```
Choice emptyChoice = new Choice();
    emptyChoice.name = "";
    emptyChoice.price = null;

    option.choices.remove(emptyChoice);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ConcurrentModificationException` happened because you tried to remove the elements outside of the `Iterator` iterating over the list.

Something like this works:

```
Iterator<Choice> iterator = option.choices.iterator(); // or use option.choices.listIterator()

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (emptyChoice.equals(iterator.next())) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, this is elegant and effective. Will select as correct as soon as I can.

Comment: I just added a ) at the end of the if statement

Answer (score 2):

> then I did this (after implementing equals and hashcode), but it doesn't work, the empty values are still there

`List.remove()` removes only the first element that matches (the one with the lowest index). To remove them all, you could put it in a loop (`remove()` returns boolean `true` if it succeeds):

```
while ( option.choices.remove(emptyElement) );
```